# What is this argument that you can send to Angular's $interval service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intervals

If I pass an argument to the anonymous function when running Angular's $interval service, there's a number that increases with every iteration.

e.g.

```
var counter = $interval(function(n) {
    console.log(n); // increases by one every iteration 
}, 1000);
```

I have included this jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/v3xLop5m/

It seems to keep increasing even after I run `$interval.cancel(animation)` and I'm wondering if it's a clue or a red herring to solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Angular passes the current iteration count as an argument to the callback function. So, in your example, the value of `n` is the iteration count, and it is displayed every second, as you passed 1000ms for the interval delay.

The usage of `$interval` is the following:

```
$interval(fn, delay, [count], [invokeApply], [Pass]);
```

And the documentation about the first argument, the callback function, says:

> A function that should be called repeatedly. If no **additional** arguments are passed, the function is called with the current iteration count.

As you passed only two arguments to `$interval`, you are in the case with no additional argument.

See for reference the [documentation for $interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

As a side note, if you write `var counter = $interval(...)`, the proper call for cancelling the interval is `$interval.cancel(counter)`.